# Is this the correct way to ensure data is loaded in the view model?

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, initialization, prism

I am building a Xamarin.Forms application using the Prism MVVM framework. I have a case where my viewmodels can receive either full objects that will be used in the view model to update data for a list view or other UI elements or it will receive just the Ids of those objects where I can use them and retrieve the full objects from a web service, but, this is an async operation and by the time the view is loaded and the list view is ready to receive the data, those objects might not have been set. I wrote a viewmodel in such a way that I think this will ensure that the listview doesn't attempt to refresh until those objects are set. I thought about using async void (fire and forget) method to retrieve the objects but that would mean that if by the time the listview is loaded, the web request might still be waiting in the background and then the refresh method would try to retrieve the same objects again causing duplicate requests.

```
//ViewModelBase implements INaviagtionAware and INotifyPropertyChanged
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _object1Id;
    private string _object2Id;
    private Task _getObjectsFromIdsTask;
    private Object1 _object1;
    private Object2 _object2;
    private DelegateCommand _refreshListViewSourceCommand;
    private bool _isIsRefreshing;
    public Object1 Object1
    {
        get => _object1;
        set => SetProperty(ref _object1, value);
    }
    public Object2 Object2
    {
        get => _object2;
        set => SetProperty(ref _object2, value);
    }
    public DelegateCommand RefreshListViewSourceCommand => _refreshListViewSourceCommand ?? (_refreshListViewSourceCommand = new DelegateCommand(RefreshListViewSource, CanExecuteRefreshListViewSource).ObservesProperty(() => IsRefreshing));
    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get => _isIsRefreshing;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isIsRefreshing, value);
    }
    public MainPageViewModel ( INavigationService navigationService )
    : base ( navigationService )
    {
        Title = "Main Page";
    }
    //Called when the page is first loadded and on each pull-to-refresh.
    private async void RefreshListViewSource ()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        try
        {
            //If this is truen then objects where set from either another viewmodel or the task has completed succesfully before this method was called from the view.
            if ( Object1 != null &&
                 Object2 != null )
            {
                //Populate the listview.
                IsRefreshing = false;
                return;
            }
            else if ( _getObjectsFromIdsTask != null )
            {
                switch ( _getObjectsFromIdsTask.Status )
                {
                    case TaskStatus.Created :
                    case TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation :
                    case TaskStatus.WaitingToRun :
                    case TaskStatus.Running :
                    case TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete :
                        //If any of the above then we wait for its completion.
                        await _getObjectsFromIdsTask;
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.Faulted :
                    case TaskStatus.Canceled :
                        //If an error occurs then we restart the task.
                        _getObjectsFromIdsTask = GetObjectsFromIds ();
                        await _getObjectsFromIdsTask;
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion :
                        //If completed then do nothing.
                        break;
                    default :
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //If it is null then this method was called from the view before the task is set.
                //This branch should never be reached, should I delete it.
                _getObjectsFromIdsTask = GetObjectsFromIds ();
                await _getObjectsFromIdsTask;
            }

            //If we get to here then the objects must be set
            //Populate the listview.
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine ( e );
        }

        IsRefreshing = false;
    }
    private bool CanExecuteRefreshListViewSource () => !IsRefreshing;
    //Gets the objects from a web service by thier ids.
    private async Task GetObjectsFromIds ()
    {
        //Uses _objectId1 and _objectId2 to get the objects. This just simulates delay.
        Task < Object1 > object1 = Task.Delay ( 100 ).ContinueWith ( task => new Object1 () );
        Task < Object2 > object2 = Task.Delay ( 100 ).ContinueWith ( task => new Object2 () );
        Object1 = await object1;
        Object2 = await object2;
    }
    //called when navigation to the page. I used OnNavigatingTo and not OnNavigatedTo to reduce the chance that the refresh method would be called befor the objects are set.
    public override void OnNavigatingTo ( NavigationParameters parameters )
    {
        base.OnNavigatingTo ( parameters );
        //If Ids are sent from another viewmodel then I have to get their objects from a web service. This would happen in case of deep linking from notification or a similar scenario.
        if ( parameters.ContainsKey ( "Object1Id" ) &&
             parameters.ContainsKey ( "Object2Id" ) )
        {
            _object1Id = parameters.GetValue < string > ( "Object1" );
            _object2Id = parameters.GetValue < string > ( "Object2" );
            _getObjectsFromIdsTask = GetObjectsFromIds ();
        }
        //If the full objects are sent, then I am setting the objects right here.
        else if ( parameters.ContainsKey ( "Object1" ) &&
                  parameters.ContainsKey ( "Object2" ) )
        {
            Object1 = parameters.GetValue < Object1 > ( "Object1" );
            Object2 = parameters.GetValue < Object2 > ( "Object2" );
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to load the data individually on each page? why not call the web method and get all the items. Store the data on local DB. Then, show them when needed?

Comment: In case you need to call the web methods in each page, you will need to show loading overlay so users can see that page is loading and wait for it to show the data.